# If $f(x)=o(\log^{(k)}(x))$ for all $k$, can $f$ diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

> Is there a divergent monotone non-decreasing continuous positive real-function $f$ such that
>   $$\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{\log^{(k)}(x)} = 0$$
>   for all $k\geqslant 1$? (By $\log^{(k)}(x)$ I mean $\underbrace{\log\log\cdots\log}_{k \text{ times}}(x)$.)

I have a strange feeling that this is false, and, although, very unlikely to be false at the same time. A cool implication of a "no" would be that if you consider the poset $\langle \mathbb{P},\prec\rangle$ consisting of divergent monotone non-decreasing continuous positive real-functions defined in $[a,+\infty)$ for some $a\geqslant 0$ (note that $a$ is *not* fixed) with the order

$$f\prec g \iff f = o(g),$$
the set $\{\log^{(k)} : k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ would be a countable dense subset of $\mathbb{P}$ (in the sense of *dense* in a partial order). **This** is exactly what "feels" to be unlikely to me.

Any tips in prove, disprove or even in to find a dense subset of $\mathbb{P}$ are welcome.

Comment: I find $\log^k x$ a highly misleading notation; to me it is standard for $(\log x)^k$. I think $\log_k x$ is preferable (even though a different notation clashes with that), or at least $\log^{(k)}x$ (although that can mean derivatives as well).

Comment: @GregMartin This was difficult to me to choose haha. Since $\log(x)^k$ is generally more common than $\log^k(x)$ to represent $(\log x)^k$, I thought that this would be the "less bad" way to write $\log\log\cdots\log(x)$ in a short way.

Comment: @GregMartin Although... I think you're right, $\log^{(k)}x$ seems way better. Fix'd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact if $g_k:[a_k,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ is any sequence of functions such that $\lim_{x\to \infty}g_k(x) = \infty$ for all $k,$ then there exists an increasing continuous $f: [0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ with $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x) = \infty$ such that

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g_k(x)} = 0$$

for all $k.$

Proof idea: Choose $0<b_1<b_2 < \cdots \to \infty $ such that

$$\min(g_1,\dots ,g_k)> 3^k \text {on} \,[b_k,\infty).$$

Define $f$ so that $2^k\le f \le 2^{k+1}$ on $[b_k, b_{k+1}].$

Comment: That was quite comprehensive! Many thanks!

Comment: And apply this repeatedly to get another sequence of functions, then apply this to that, and you get a function that grows almost as slowly as my income.

Comment: Perhaps your income function is a counterexample to "there is no slowest growing function".

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. The ["log-star" function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm) satisfies everything you want except for continuity, but it's easy to interpolate it to make it continuous.