# Is there a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is not complete?

Tags: general-topology

Is there a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is not complete?
Thanks in advanced

Comment: Is $\Bbb{Q}$ complete?

Comment: @Race: Is $\Bbb Q$ connected?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Normal Human said any subset, not any connected subset.

Comment: Any open and bounded subset under the usual topology isn't closed: therefore there are points on the boundary which are the limits of sequences in the set, but the boundary points are not contained in the set.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is not complete nor connected. Any closed subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ is complete

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connectedness of sets in the plane with rational coordinates and at least one irrational](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17460/connectedness-of-sets-in-the-plane-with-rational-coordinates-and-at-least-one-ir)

Comment: @Tomek: It most definitely is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: I don't understand what is the fuss on this question, relating to its downvotes/upvotes. This doesn't seem homework-seeking at all: it seems like a confused person who just got introduced to Analysis, imagining things that are "connected" should have no "separation", hence be "complete". This is exactly why I tried to answer in a detailed but simple form. Is the question trivial? Yes, one could argue so. But why isn't this same behaviour being reproduced in this question, for instance?: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388242/function-grows-slower-than-lnx

Comment: I have posted about the simplest possible answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $A:=(0,2) \times \{0\}\times \{0\}... \times \{0\}$, and the sequence $x_n=(\frac{1}{n},0,0,...,0)$

It is clearly cauchy, but it doesn't converge. Why? Suppose otherwise, that $x_n \rightarrow x \in A$. Since we are taking the induced metric, this would imply that $x_n \rightarrow x$ also in $\mathbb{R}^n$. But note that $x_n \rightarrow 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since limits are unique in a metric space, we arrive at a contradiction.

Now, $A$ is connected, since it is the image of $(0,2)$ under the continuous map $i: (0,2) \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: I won't keep this answer just to get a positive score, if it is inappropriate... therefore, I must ask: why the downvotes?

Comment: There's a lot of weird downvoting today. Jupiter must be aligned with Mars.

Comment: @Aloizio: Vandalism. No telling why.

Answer (score 1):

How about the open unit ball?  This is connected but not complete.