# Does there exist any unbounded above function $f(x)$ such that $f(x)<\log(x)$ for all $x>M$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Does there exist any unbounded above function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that there is some $M > 0$ such that $f(x)<\log(x)$ for all $x>M$?

Mainly I observed the fact that $\log(x)$ has slope $0$ at infinity. 
Let

$g(x)=\log(x)$

$g'(x)= {1\over x}$

$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}g'(x)=0$

So I think $\log(x)$ is the ultimate boundary. So every unbounded function must have a slope $\ge$ slope of $\log(x) $ at infinity

Comment: There is no "boundary" in these matters. Exercise: For every function $f$ such that $f(x)\to+\infty$ when $x\to+\infty$ there exists some function $g$ such that $g(x)\to+\infty$ and $g(x)/f(x)\to0$ when $x\to+\infty$

Comment: @DEEP You got two answers to your question, are they not what you need?

Comment: Where I can find the proof?

Comment: Proof of what? $ $

Comment: Exercise: For every function f such that f(x)→+∞ when x→+∞ there exists some function g such that g(x)→+∞ and g(x)/f(x)→0 when x→+∞

Comment: @DEEP *Think*. Deeply.

Comment: I'm sorry ...I was puzzled.  Now I understand.. THANK U :-)

Comment: Along these lines, check out http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1370380/if-fx-o-logkx-for-all-k-can-f-diverges/1370407#1370407

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(x) = \log (x) - 1$ should do nicely.

Other possibilities:

- $\log(\log(x))$, or $\log(\log(\log(x)))$ and so on
- $\log(x) - C$ for some constant $C>0$
- $\log(\sqrt{x})$
- $\log(f(x))$ where $f(x)$ is any function bounded above and growing slower than $x\mapsto x$

---

If you want a function with a non-zero slope, you can take

$$f(x) = (\sin(x) + 2)\cdot \frac{\log(x)}{3} - 1$$

This function is obviously always smaller than $\log x$ and is also unbounded at $\infty$.

Its derivative is

$$f'(x) = \cos x\frac{\log x}{3} +\frac{1}{3x}(\sin x + 2)$$

so the slope is not zero and does not approach zero at $\infty$.

Comment: Logically undeniable. But I guess the OP wants to seek a function, which is not articulated clearly however, that grows slower than $\log x$. :)

Comment: @GudsonChou Why would he want a function which is not articulated clearly?

Comment: I meant that the OP might not state what he wants clearly enough.

Comment: @GudsonChou You are probably right. if the answer is not what he needs, he should tell us that either by commenting or editing the question.

Comment: Right on. No worry, +1 for any correct answers.

Comment: you can find that all these functions have same slope when $x \to \infty$ and that is the slope of $log(x)$ at infinity

Comment: @DEEP You never said that you need a different slope. Anyway, I now edited my answer with another example.

Comment: I'm sorry ...I was puzzled.  Now I understand.. THANK U :-)

Answer (score 3):

Or if you want something growing "a lot" slower, take $f(x) = \log \log x$. (For $x$ large enough.)

Comment: A more creative one would be $f(x) = \dfrac1x$ (but probably not what the OP had in mind).

Comment: here $lim_{x\to \infty}f'(x) = 0$, i.e $log(log(x))$ has same slope as $log(x)$ when $x$ tends to $\infty$

Comment: I'm sorry ...I was puzzled.  Now I understand.. THANK U :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just like there is no minimal positive real number, there is no minimal rate of unbounded growth. If $\def\R{\Bbb R}f:(a,+\infty)\to\R$ is any increasing unbounded function, then $x\to f(\log x)$ is a function also an increasing and unbounded function $(\exp(a),+\infty)\to\R$ that is dominated by it.

This construction does not quite guarantee an asymptotically slower rate of growth, but you'll have to work hard to construct to construct a function for which it doesn't (something like inverse [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration)). But even then there is asymptotically (much!) slower still, like the [inverse Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Inverse).